# Refactoring MySQL queries to a single query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a nice way of doing this.

Basically i have a hundred rows and i am ordering in ascending order to find the least popular.  If the least is not unique i am concerned with obviously the size of the subset - number of rows with equal "pop" (popularity ranking).  In order to determine the size of this subset i have the following code.

However, being a novice ,i am conscious that it seems a little clumsy.

```
$leastpop = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM homepage ORDER BY pop ASC   LIMIT 1 ");

$pop = mysql_fetch_array($leastpop); 

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM homepage WHERE pop = '$pop'");  

$count = mysql_num_rows($check);

if($count>=1)
{
//find the element with the corresponding "oldest date"



}
```

As it stands i have not even attempted to determine the "oldest date" among the subset should the size of this subset prove to be greater than one for fear of repeating the same clumsy queries.

Is there a better and more efficient way of approaching this problem? I hope i have been clear enough.  Cheers.

Comment: You are using `LIMIT 1` so your result set is always 1 record if there are rows. What exactly do you want the result to be?

Comment: I want the least popular.  So assuming all elements were unique the current method (limit 1) would do it.  But what happens if say many rows have pop = 0?  I need to know the size of this subset as i will have to determine a single row by another criteria (the oldest date - date of joining)...

Comment: These additional criteria should be in your `WHERE` clause. This way, the `LIMIT 1` will still work.

Comment: But doesn't that amount to the same thing - knowing the oldest date in an array?  What happens if many dates concur?  Is the above the only way of going about it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe trying a query along these lines will help:

`select pop, count(*), min(date_field) from homepage group by pop order by pop ASC limit 1;`

This will give you the least popular pop, with the count of rows for that pop and the oldest date (minimum date). These functions are called aggregation functions, because they do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mysql_*` anymore for new code if possible, go `mysqli` or `PDO`.

```
 SELECT h1.* FROM homepage h1
 LEFT JOIN homepage h2
 ON h2.pop <= h1.pop AND h2.date_column <= h1.date_column
 WHERE h2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: rather mysql_* function causes  E_DEPRECATED warning in php5.5 https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the least popular with the oldest date, you just need one (simple...) query:

```
SELECT * FROM homepage ORDER BY pop, insert_date LIMIT 1
```

If there are multiple records that match the same criteria, mysql will just give you the first one it finds. If that is not specific enough, you would have to add more criteria; either using `WHERE` or by adding more fields to the `ORDER BY` clause.

And as mentioned before, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so you should switch to PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use subqueries:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM homepage WHERE pop IN (SELECT h2.pop FROM homepage AS h2 ORDER BY h2.pop ASC LIMIT 1)");
```